# Screenly display mirrored to two displays

Tags: pi-3

Wondering the best method to mirror the output from a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Screenly Pro to two displays (display panels with HDMI input).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a HDMI splitter box. You can get them for about 20 bucks on amazon. I use this one: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B01615JA3A